# IllegalArgumentException: reason Phrase can't be empty. only occurring in tabs and emulator tabs

Tags: tabs, android-emulator, illegalargumentexception

```
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClientCompat() {
            override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView?, errorCode: Int, description: String?, failingUrl: String?) {
                if (view!!.url.equals(failingUrl)) {
                    toast(getString(R.string.please_try_when_internet_available))
                    webView.clearHistory()
                    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, sHtmlTemplate, "text/html", "utf-8", null)
                }
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl)
            }

            override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest, error: WebResourceErrorCompat) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
            }
        }
```

This exception crashing for above set of code only for tabs and emulator tabs working good in devices.Also tried to catch inside try-catch block and not working.